# Format XML using command line

Tags: html, xml, bash, format, tidy

I have a html text file and i want to format it so that paragraphs are always on the same line e.g.

```
<p>paragraph info here</p>
```

instead of

```
<p>paragraph
info here </p>
```

Is there a tool that enables me to do this

Comment: `sed` or `awk` can help you.

Comment: Suprisingly your best bet would be to use an xml parser

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`

```
 cat test.html |sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' |sed 's/<\/p> /<\/p>\n/g'
```

In first run it remove all line break and then add it after paragraph tag

It is not clear but it work

Comment: What about lines that are not in between <p> ... </p>?

Answer (score 0):

While the requirement *paragraphs are always on the same line* would be met by simply joining the whole file to a single line, this solution is less radical:

```
perl -pe 'if (/<p>/../<\/p>/) { s/\n/ / unless /<\/p>/ }' test.html
```